# Notify OP that the bug report has viewed by site owners

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, notifications

I am suggesting that owner of a post should get notified when the site owners/developers/managers have viewed your post at least once, if the post contains the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag. The comment might look like:

> At least one of the site owners have viewed your post and you will receive a response soon.

I have already gone through [asking targeted users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183239/221351) and [notify group of users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71728/221351). And I agree with them completely. I understand that Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a consulting site.  But if the question asked is of [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) type, then the site maintainers are the ones who should look in the matters.

Other people viewing, commenting, answering is fine by me, and it is highly appreciated.

With reference to this [bug submitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186643/221351), I think I have enough views already, but I've seen no comments or answers. I'm left to wonder if the bug report has been noticed or went unnoticed.

I am suggesting that just one comment in the question section be automatically generated if at least one of the site owners views the page containing bug tag.

Hope this doesn't goes unnoticed. ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We [are working on getting better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/why-dont-we-get-responses-from-bug-reports/186824#186824) at responding more quickly to bug reports. They *are* generally seen rather quickly by both the development and community management teams. Bugs that look to be serious are immediately escalated up the chain and put in front of someone that can evaluate and (ideally) quickly fix whatever issue is at hand.

However, we really don't have the capacity to notify people when a developer (someone that can actually address your issue) has opened a question that has the bug tag. Beyond being quite difficult to differentiate a developer from someone that works here but isn't a developer, we don't want to interfere with the developer's ability to efficiently triage bug reports. They know best which bugs are minor or severe, and how many users are affected by a given bug. Knowing that they set off some kind of alert to the user just by viewing the page would add a bit of pressure or incentive for them to break out of their plan and try to fix things on the spot, when they really need to be fixing stuff in the order that they've agreed upon as a team.

Note, some seemingly minor bugs may seem minor, but might require some heavy refactoring in order to *really* be fixed properly. Additionally, some may be blocked by pending changes, or others may be fixed when they merge next - given the amount that we have it's impossible to recall the details and status of each.

What I can say is - if you post a bug report, *it does get seen rather quickly*. We can't always comment in short order because it would require 20 minutes of searching to see if we can find something related, or determine if it is in fact a new bug. Many issues get reported multiple times.

I did, however, leave a comment on the one that you posted. I can't reproduce it, so I'll need to determine your browser info to see if this might actually *be* fixed and regressed, or if it's going to be taken care of with a pending change.

Comment: Happy to know, that my words didn't feel on deaf ears.. I agree with bug cannot be solved immediately as I am a developer myself, And its completely fine if it gets solved in days to come, NO PRESSURE there..But I would still insist on some kind of system generated notification if bug is valid.. Say, we can have reviewers team voting for the genuine bugs, then after a particular count you can at-least view it/comment on it. All said, I always enjoy to share my knowledge on stackoverflow and will continue so.. Thank u guys for good work..

Comment: There are notifications when a bug is acted on, but they might not be obvious. A developer will edit the tags of your report to say 'status-completed', 'status-deferred', 'status-norepro', 'status-reproduced' or 'status-declined' occasionally if it's a feature request. You'll be notified of the edit in your global inbox, and the accompanying comment or reply that (almost always) follows. Where we could do a little better is precisely where you describe, which is just some indication that it's been acknowledged - but doing it automatically wouldn't work well.

Comment: To that end, we _probably_ could comment a little more. We really _do_ see these quickly, and you're not the first recently wondering if we've gone deaf. I'm going to discuss this a bit more after the holiday.

Comment: Thank u for the insight.. no questions on quality of service you guys provide... Hope we find better way of acknowledge of bug report in near future..